# Match Two Separate Xpath Queries

Tags: xpath

I need to find the first record on a page that matches two queries:

First Query; **that it ships from the UK**

```
<span class="mplabel">Ships From:</span>United Kingdom</li>
```

Second Query; that it shows the text snippet **"handled by a previous owner who took good"**

```
   <span class="tooltip-inner xh-highlight">
                                            Will show some signs that it was played and otherwise handled by a previous owner who took good care of it.            
                </span>
```

I am using variations of this but cannot seem to match both queries:

```
(//li[contains(text(), 'United Kingdom')]/preceding::span[contains(text(), 'took good care')][1]/following::td[@class='seller_info']/ul/li[4]/strong/a)[1]
```

For example, on this URL it matches with a seller from Belgium, which is incorrect:

https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/106601

Example of one div below:

```
<tr class="shortcut_navigable unavailable" data-release-id="10206212">
    <td class="item_picture as_float">
        
        <div class="hide_mobile community_data_text">
                    <div class="community_rating">
        Rated: <strong>4.56</strong>
    </div>

<div class="community_summary community_fixed_width">
                
                                                            
            
                <div class="community_result">
            <span class="have_indicator high_have" style="width:100%;">
                <span class="community_number">260</span>
            </span>
            <span class="community_label">260 have</span>
        </div>
                        <div class="community_result">
            <span class="want_indicator " style="width:27.307692307692307%;">
                <span class="community_number"> 71</span>
            </span>
            <span class="community_label">71 want</span>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="hide-desktop">
                        
<span class="price">£2.99</span>
<br>
        <span class="converted_price"><span>about</span> €3.40</span>
    <span class=" item_shipping">
    +<button class="show-shipping-methods" data-item-id="" data-seller-username="deeman" data-seller-id="49398">shipping</button></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="item_description">
            <strong>
    <a href="/sell/item/1931906849" class="item_description_title" data-followable="true">Billy Idol - Rebel Yell (Extended Version)  (12", Single)</a>
</strong>
<br>

        <p class="hide-desktop muted">
                        Unavailable in Australia                    </p>

<p class="hide_mobile label_and_cat">
    <span class="mplabel">Label:</span><a href="https://www.discogs.com/label/3198-Chrysalis">Chrysalis</a>, <a href="https://www.discogs.com/label/3198-Chrysalis">Chrysalis</a><br>

    <span class="mplabel">Cat#:</span>
    <span class="item_catno">IDOLX 6, IDOLX6</span>
    <br>
</p>

<p class="item_condition">
    <span class="mplabel condition-label-desktop">
        Media Condition:
    </span>
    <span class="mplabel condition-label-mobile">Media:</span>
            
<span>
    Very Good Plus (VG+)

                <span class="has-tooltip" role="note" tabindex="0">
            <i class="icon icon-info-circle muted" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tooltip multi-line-tooltip sr-only" role="tooltip">
                <span class="tooltip-inner xh-highlight">
                                            Will show some signs that it was played and otherwise handled by a previous owner who took good care of it.            
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
        </span>


    <br>

                <span class="mplabel condition-label-desktop">Sleeve Condition:</span>
        <span class="mplabel condition-label-mobile">Sleeve:</span>
        <span class="item_sleeve_condition">Very Good (VG)</span>
        <br>
        </p>

<p class="hide_mobile">
            Sleeve has no splits and is close to VG+ . . . . . . . ACCURATE, HONEST &amp; DESCRIPTIVE GRADINGS • COMPETITIVE PRICES • FAST DISPATCH • Please read seller terms<br>

</p>



<a href="/release/10206212-Billy-Idol-Rebel-Yell-Extended-Version-" class="item_release_link hide_mobile">View Release Page</a>


    </td>
    <td class="seller_info">
            <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="seller_block">
            <span class="mplabel seller_label">Seller:</span>
            <strong><a href="/seller/deeman/profile">deeman</a></strong>

                        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
                                        
        <span class="star_rating" alt="deeman rating 4.5 stars out of 5" role="img" aria-label="deeman rating 4.5 out of 5"><i role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-star"></i><i role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-star"></i><i role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-star"></i><i role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-star"></i><i role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-star-half-empty"></i></span> 
<strong>99.8%</strong><span>,</span>    <a href="/sell/seller_feedback/deeman" target="_top" class="section_link">
    466 ratings    </a>
        </li>
    <li class="xh-highlight"><span class="mplabel">Ships From:</span>United Kingdom</li>

                <li class="seller_mywants in_wantlist has_count loaded" data-username="deeman" data-seller-id="49398">
            <i class="icon icon-spinner icon-spin" role="img" aria-label="loading more information"></i>
            <strong>
                <a href="/seller/deeman/mywants?ev=hxiiw">Has 1 item I want</a>
            </strong>
        </li>
    
</ul>

    </td>
    <td class="hide-desktop mobile-description">
                </td>
    <td class="item_price hide_mobile">
                    
<span class="price">£2.99</span>
<br>
        <span class="converted_price"><span>about</span> €3.40</span>
    <span class=" item_shipping">
    +<button class="show-shipping-methods" data-item-id="" data-seller-username="deeman" data-seller-id="49398">shipping</button></span>
    </td>

                <td class="item_add_to_cart hide_mobile cart_button_substitute_text muted">
                                Unavailable in Australia                            </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want it to return the "seller_feedback"-url, right?

First and foremost I would highly recommend you parse and re-indent/"prettify" the HTML-source for a better overview of all the element-nodes and its direct parents/children. Some element-nodes in the XPath query you tried are not where you think they are, or aren't there at all.

I don't know what XPath-processor you're using, but with the command-line tool [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) the following query works for me (although in this case it doesn't return a match):

```bash
$ xidel -s "https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/106601" -e '
  //tr[
    @class="shortcut_navigable " and contains(
      td[@class="item_description"]//span[@class="tooltip-inner"],
      "took good care"
    )
  ]/td[@class="seller_info"]/ul[
    li[span[@class="mplabel"]]/normalize-space(text()) = "United Kingdom"
  ]/li[span[@class="star_rating"]]/a/resolve-uri(@href)
'
```

To re-indent/"prettify" the HTML-source with `xidel` you could do:

```bash
$ xidel -s "https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/106601" -e . \
  --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work unfortunately. What I essentially want to do is combine these two queries so the XPATH finds me the first record that matched both. //tbody/following::li[contains(text(), 'United Kingdom')]

//tbody/following::span[contains(text(), 'took good care')]